# Swapping within an Array of user inputs

Tags: c, arrays, swap

I am here to get some advice on how to continue my program. It is a homework assignment and the idea is to have another method called      `int is_sorted(int array[], int length);`
With these pre and post conditions.

1. Precondition: array will be an array of integers of length length.
2. Postcondition: returns true if the array is in sorted(nondecreasing) order, or false otherwise.

So far I have been able to put together the user input array and how long it should be.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int is_sorted(int array[], int lenght);

int is_sorted(int array[], int lenght)
{
    int swap;
    int smallest;
    int index = 0;
    scanf("%d", &lenght);

    int list[lenght];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &list[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{

}
```

How would I go about asking for a user input to swap two elements at a time within the given array?

The final product should look similar to this:

> Sample Run: User input in bold
>
> **4** <- The length that the array should be.
>
> **1 1 1 2** <- user input these 4 numbers.
>
> WHAT IS THE NEXT SWAP? **2 3**
>
> EVAN HAS UNSORTED THE ARRAY.
>
> WHAT IS THE NEXT SWAP? **2 0**
>
> WHAT IS THE NEXT SWAP? **0 3**
>
> EVAN HAS SORTED THE ARRAY.
>
> WHAT IS THE NEXT SWAP? **-1 -1**
>
> STEVE WAS RIGHT!
>
> -1 -1 end the swapping process and check if the array is sorted.

Comment: See also [Using basic arrays to sort an input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321749/using-basic-arrays-to-sort-a-input).  Two people must be taking the same class.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the input function with the `is_sorted()` function.  The `is_sorted()` function should take an existing array and check whether it is sorted.  You need a separate function (the body of which will be similar to what you've written as the body of `is_sorted()`) to enter the array.  You also have some other work to do — keeping track of whether the array was sorted before and is sorted now.  And printing appropriate comments.  It's funny that EVAN has sorted the array but STEVE is right.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(i != -1 && j != -1){
    scanf("%d %d", &i, &j);
    swap(&array[i], &array[j]);
}
```

and `swap()` looks like this:

```
void swap(int* a, int* b){
    int c = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = c;
}
```

There's probably a nifty trick for swaping two variables doing some bitwise xor-ing that I don't remember about.